# How to run a script before helm install?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Could not find anything about this in the documentation.

What I want to achieve is to copy a file into a subchart's directory which will be used by the entrypoint of the image.

The problem what I want to solve is to avoid subchart unpacking and copying the file by hand into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Helm point of view, there are [Helm Chart Hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/). They allows you to execute custom images (with custom commands). You can check `pre-install` hook.

For your use case though, since you want to execute something before really executing the Helm command, you may want to end up with a bash script which executes something before `helm install`.